# What Integral Measures When we calculate integral of Functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory

As we know, the integral of function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{C}$ is defined $$ \int\limits_a^bf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\int\limits_a^b\operatorname{Re}[f(t)]\,\mathrm{d}t\,+\,i \int\limits_a^b\operatorname{Im}[f(t)]\,\mathrm{d}t$$
But, I am curious to know how we defined this integral in this way? Why?
As integral of any function $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ measures area. But I also want to know what the integral of $f$  measures?

Comment: It makes it linear, basically. It doesn't really measure area anymore, not really.

Comment: @Ian I think you could basically make that an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the point is to preserve the property that $f \mapsto \int_a^b f(t) dt$ is a linear mapping. It doesn't really measure area anymore.

Comment: Yes, I know that it does not measure area . But What's the reason behind defining the integral of these type of functions.

Comment: @user477157 It should be linear, so if you know what it should mean when the function takes only real values and when it takes only imaginary values then this is the only linear way to stitch them together.